# Organic Search Sources for gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm using the following snippet for GA:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-146420495-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXX-X');
</script>
```

In my GA reports I see that Yandex (russian search engine) is considered a referer:
[image]

I tried adding it to "Organic Search Sources" in property settings in GA like this:
[image]

But it does not help.

How can I make GA treat Yandex (with all its regional sites) as organic search source?

Comment: I did some quick testing on this, and even though yandex.ru and yandex.com are listed on the default search engine list, traffic via search from yandex.ru was being reported as referral traffic. Adding it to the list did not fix the issue, it was still seen as referral traffic. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821?hl=en

Comment: @BronwynV right, this is the issue I see

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose it is advisable to create 2 custom filters:

- Advanced
- Search and replace

The **Advanced** filter will be used to transform the medium from *referral* to *organic*.

The **Search and replace** filter will then have the function of transforming all the various domains (y*andex.ru, yandex.by, yandex.kz, yandex.ua, etc ...*) into the generic *yandex*.

https://www.analyticstraps.com/yandex-e-visto-come-referral-anziche-organico/